# Jersey ContainerResponseFilter not working

Tags: java, web-services, jersey, jax-rs

I'm using **Jersey** and I implemented a ContainerRequestFilter.
Now I also want to add a **ContainerResponseFilter** to add a header to each request but nothing happens when the webservice is accessed.

This is how the filter looks like:

```
public class ResponseFilter implements ContainerResponseFilter {

    @Override
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext requestContext, ContainerResponseContext responseContext) throws IOException {

        MultivaluedMap<String, Object> headers = responseContext.getHeaders();
        headers.add("Cache-Control", "whatever");
    }
}
```

My jersey dependencies:

```
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.core:jersey-client:2.18'
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.containers:jersey-container-servlet-core:2.18'
compile 'org.glassfish.jersey.media:jersey-media-json-jackson:2.18'
```

I register the providers in an xml like this:

```
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>controller.webservice</param-value>
    </init-param>
    //This is the request filter, which is working fine
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>model.filter.AuthenticationFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    //Response filter, does not work
    <init-param>
        <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
        <param-value>model.filter.ResponseFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Jersey REST Service</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

This didn't work, so I tried to register the provider with the annotation *@Provider* and in the webservice like this:

```
register(TokenModifier.class);
```

But none of these worked. I read several other posts but I couldn't find an answer to it. Does anyone have a thought on this?

Comment: Can you show the full web.xml and the list of your Jersey related dependencies

Comment: @peeskillet, I edited my question, you'll see them now

Comment: This just a guess. I have not tried it, nor do I know if it is the cause, but what happens if you comma separate the init-param, i.e. put both filters the `...classnames` init-param, separated by comma. I am just guessing that maybe you can only have one of the same init-param. But we can speficy multiple components separated by comma or semi-colon inside of a single init-param

Comment: Secondly, the `@Provider` is discovered by the package scanning. Currently for the package scan, you only have this package listed `controller.webservice`. So if the filter is not in that package (or a subpackage, like `controller.webservice.filters`), the `@Provider` annotation will not get picked up. Like the `..classnames` init-param, the `..packages` init-param also accepts multiple packages separated by comma or semi-colon

Comment: Great, adding the package where the filter is in the xml and annotating it with Provider did the trick. If you write it in the answer I'll accept it. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This init-param

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>controller.webservice</param-value>
</init-param>
```

is used by Jersey to scan package(s) listed for `@Path` and `@Provider` annotated classes, and register them. The package(s) listed will be recursively scanned. So for example, with your current configuration, all the following packages will get scanned

```
controller.webservice
controller.webservice.x
controller.webservice.x.y
controller.webservice.x.y.z
```

The value of the param can also be multiple values separated by a comma or semi-colon. So if your filter is in a different package base, you can add that package to the list of packages to scan

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>controller.webservice, com.my.filters</param-value>
</init-param>
```

Personally though, if I'm using web.xml, I will just use one base package, and have all other packages extend from that package. Something like

```
com.company.app
com.company.app.domain
com.company.app.filters
com.company.app.resources
```

Then you can just put the `com.company.app` as the init-param value, and all other sub packages will get scanned also.

Comment: You just ended my 24 hours search for solution. Thank you